# where to download the iphone sdk 3.1

Tags: iphone

where can i get the iphone sdk 3.1? i want to create iphone applications ut i dont want to enroll in the apple dev. program. i dont need the latest sdk because i dont have a snow leopard but the leopard os only..

Answer (score 2):

You have to get a free developers account and sign the user's agreement before you can download the SDK. The free SDK will let you develop on the simulator.

If you want to test on the device (without jailbreaking) you will need the developers account to get a signing certificate.

Comment: If you want to **legaly** test on the device...